# Python websocket multithread real time data question

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, multiprocessing

I'm trying to build a terminal application that send request to a server and receive real time data back via websocket(data is in JSON format). Meanwhile, I want to save the data in a list. The above functions is in one thread. The second thread will loop through the list and print the data out(it's supposed to update my database but for simplicity sake I'm just printing it out now). But somehow the second thread doesn't seem to be starting or the data are not appended to the list so that there is nothing to print.
The following is my code:

```
from functools import partial
import sys
import time
import getopt
import requests
import socket
import json
import websocket
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process




def process_data(dataBuffer):
    if len(dataBuffer) > 0:
        for data in dataBuffer:
           
            if data['Key']['Name'] == "CNY=X":
               print("CNY: " , data['Fields']['BID'], data['Fields']['ASK'], data['Fields']['PCTCHNG'], data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1'], data['Fields']['PRIMACT_1'])
        if data['Key']['Name'] == "TWD=X":
            print("TWD: " , data['Fields']['BID'], data['Fields']['ASK'], data['Fields']['PCTCHNG'], data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1'], data['Fields']['PRIMACT_1'])
                #if obj['Key']['Name'] == "CNY=X":
                #    print("CNY: " , obj['Fields']['BID'], obj['Fields']['ASK'], obj['Fields']['PCTCHNG'], obj['Fields']['NETCHNG_1'], obj['Fields']['PRIMACT_1'])
                #if obj['Key']['Name'] == "TWD=X":
                #    print("TWD: " , obj['Fields']['BID'], obj['Fields']['ASK'], obj['Fields']['PCTCHNG'], obj['Fields']['NETCHNG_1'], obj['Fields']['PRIMACT_1'])

def process_message(message_json):
    """ Parse at high level and output JSON of message """
    message_type = message_json['Type']
    global dataBuffer
    if message_type == "Refresh":
        if 'Domain' in message_json:
            message_domain = message_json['Domain']
            if message_domain == "Login":
                process_login_response(message_json)
            
        dataBuffer.append(message_json)
    elif message_type == "Ping":
        pong_json = {'Type': 'Pong'}
        web_socket_app.send(json.dumps(pong_json))
        print("SENT:")
        print(json.dumps(pong_json, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ':')))
    elif message_json['Type'] == "Update":
         dataBuffer.append(message_json)
    
    
def process_login_response(message_json):
    """ Send item request """
    send_market_price_request(ric)


def send_market_price_request(ric_name):
    """ Create and send simple Market Price request """
    mp_req_json = {
        'ID': 2,
        'Key': {
            'Name': ric_name,
            'Service': service
        },
    }
    web_socket_app.send(json.dumps(mp_req_json))
    print("SENT:")
    print(json.dumps(mp_req_json, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ':')))


def send_login_request(auth_token, is_refresh_token):
    """
        Send login request with authentication token.
        Used both for the initial login and subsequent reissues to update the authentication token
"""
    
    web_socket_app.send(json.dumps(login_json))
    print("SENT:")
    print(json.dumps(login_json, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ':')))


def on_message( _, message):
    """ Called when message received, parse message into JSON for processing """
    #global dataBuffer
    
    print("RECEIVED: ")
    message_json = json.loads(message)
    print(json.dumps(message_json, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ':')))
    for singleMsg in message_json:
        process_message(singleMsg)
       
 

def on_error(_, error):
    """ Called when websocket error has occurred """
    print(error)


def on_close(_, close_status_code, close_msg):
    """ Called when websocket is closed """
    


def on_open(_):
    """ Called when handshake is complete and websocket is open, send login """

    print("WebSocket successfully connected!")
    global web_socket_open
    web_socket_open = True
    send_login_request(sts_token, False)


def get_sts_token(current_refresh_token, url=None):
    """
        Retrieves an authentication token.
        :param current_refresh_token: Refresh token retrieved from a previous authentication, used to retrieve a
        subsequent access token. If not provided (i.e. on the initial authentication), the password is used.
    """


###
user = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'
clientid = 'xxx'

###

# Global Default Variables
app_id = '256'
auth_url = 'https://api.refinitiv.com:443/auth/oauth2/v1/token'
#hostname = 'ap-southeast-1-aws-1-lrg.optimized-pricing-api.refinitiv.net'
hostname ='ap-northeast-1-aws-1-sm.optimized-pricing-api.refinitiv.net'
port = '443'
scope = 'trapi.streaming.pricing.read'

position = ''
sts_token = ''
refresh_token = ''
client_secret = ''
service = 'ELEKTRON_DD'

# Global Variables
web_socket_app = None
web_socket_open = False
logged_in = False
original_expire_time = '0';
dataBuffer = []


ric = ["CNY=X", "TWD=X"]

###

position_host = socket.gethostname()
position = socket.gethostbyname(position_host) + "/" + position_host
sts_token, refresh_token, expire_time = get_sts_token(None)

original_expire_time = expire_time
ws_address = "wss://{}:{}/WebSocket".format(hostname, port)
web_socket_app = websocket.WebSocketApp(ws_address, on_message=on_message,on_error=on_error,on_close=on_close,subprotocols=['tr_json2'])
web_socket_app.on_open = on_open
expire_time = 60
wst = threading.Thread(target=web_socket_app.run_forever, kwargs={'sslopt': {'check_hostname':
False}})
t2 = threading.Thread(target=process_data , args=(dataBuffer,))
#wst = Process(target=web_socket_app.run_forever, kwargs={'sslopt': {'check_hostname': False}})
#t2 = Process(target=process_data, args=(dataBuffer,))
    ###
    ###
wst.start()
t2.start()
```

The following is the first json message received:

```
[
    {
      "Fields":{
        "ACTIV_DATE":"2023-08-22",
        "ACT_FLAG1":" ",
        "ACT_FLAG2":" ",
        "ACT_FLAG3":" ",
        "ACT_TP_1":"B\u21e7",
        "ACT_TP_2":"B\u21e7",
        "ACT_TP_3":"B\u21e7",
        "ACVOL_1":null,
        "ASIA_CLOSE":null,
        "ASIA_CL_DT":null,
        "ASIA_HIGH":null,
        "ASIA_HI_TM":null,
        "ASIA_LOW":null,
        "ASIA_LW_TM":null,
        "ASIA_NETCH":null,
        "ASIA_OPEN":null,
        "ASIA_OP_TM":null,
        "ASK":7.2929,
        "ASKSIZE":null,
        "ASK_1":7.2925,
        "ASK_2":7.2885,
        "ASK_HIGH_1":7.2932,
        "ASK_HI_TME":"08:26:00",
        "ASK_LOW_1":7.268,
        "ASK_LO_TME":"01:34:00",
        "ASK_SPREAD":null,
        "BCAST_REF":"CNY=",
        "BCKGRNDPAG":"    ",
        "BEST_ASIZ1":null,
        "BEST_ASIZ2":null,
        "BEST_ASIZ3":null,
        "BEST_ASIZ4":null,
        "BEST_ASIZ5":null,
        "BEST_ASK1":null,
        "BEST_ASK2":null,
        "BEST_ASK3":null,
        "BEST_ASK4":null,
        "BEST_ASK5":null,
        "BEST_BID1":null,
        "BEST_BID2":null,
        "BEST_BID3":null,
        "BEST_BID4":null,
        "BEST_BID5":null,
        "BEST_BSIZ1":null,
        "BEST_BSIZ2":null,
        "BEST_BSIZ3":null,
        "BEST_BSIZ4":null,
        "BEST_BSIZ5":null,
        "BID":7.2923,
        "BIDSIZE":null,
        "BID_1":7.2911,
        "BID_2":7.2882,
        "BID_HIGH_1":7.2926,
        "BID_LOW_1":7.267,
        "BID_NET_CH":0.0058,
        "BID_SPREAD":null,
        "BID_TICK_1":"\u21e7",
        "BKGD_REF":"Chinese Yuan",
        "BOND_TYPE":"   ",
        "BPV":null,
        "B_ASK1_TIM":null,
        "B_ASK2_TIM":null,
        "B_ASK3_TIM":null,
        "B_ASK4_TIM":null,
        "B_ASK5_TIM":null,
        "B_BID1_TIM":null,
        "B_BID2_TIM":null,
        "B_BID3_TIM":null,
        "B_BID4_TIM":null,
        "B_BID5_TIM":null,
        "CALL_PRC":null,
        "CCY_NAME":"                              ",
        "CLOSE_ASK":7.289,
        "CLOSE_BID":7.2865,
        "CLOSE_TYPE":"B ",
        "CNTCT_ID":null,
        "CONTEXT_ID":3284,
        "CONVEXITY":null,
        "CROSS_SC":"1E+00",
        "CTBLOC_ID1":"   ",
        "CTBLOC_ID2":"   ",
        "CTBLOC_ID3":"   ",
        "CTBTR_1":"Refinitiv",
        "CTBTR_2":"            ",
        "CTBTR_3":"            ",
        "CTBTR_BKGD":null,
        "CTBTR_ID1":"    ",
        "CTBTR_ID2":"    ",
        "CTBTR_ID3":"    ",
        "CTB_LOC1":"   ",
        "CTB_LOC2":"   ",
        "CTB_LOC3":"   ",
        "CTB_PAGE1":"    ",
        "CTB_PAGE2":"    ",
        "CTB_PAGE3":"    ",
        "CURRENCY":"CNY",
        "DAYS_MAT":null,
        "DEALT_VL1":null,
        "DEALT_VL2":null,
        "DEALT_VL3":null,
        "DELTA":null,
        "DLG_CODE1":"      ",
        "DLG_CODE2":"      ",
        "DLG_CODE3":"      ",
        "DSO_ID":16416,
        "DSPLY_NAME":"Refinitiv",
        "DVOL1_SC":" ",
        "DVOL2_SC":" ",
        "DVOL3_SC":" ",
        "EMAIL_ADRS":"                                        ",
        "EURO_CLOSE":null,
        "EURO_CL_DT":null,
        "EURO_HIGH":null,
        "EURO_HI_TM":null,
        "EURO_LOW":null,
        "EURO_LW_TM":null,
        "EURO_NETCH":null,
        "EURO_OPEN":null,
        "EURO_OP_TM":null,
        "FIX_DATE":null,
        "FWD1_PRICE":null,
        "FWD2_PRICE":null,
        "GEN_TEXT16":"                ",
        "GEN_VAL1":null,
        "GEN_VAL10":null,
        "GEN_VAL2":null,
        "GEN_VAL3":null,
        "GEN_VAL4":null,
        "GEN_VAL5":null,
        "GEN_VAL6":null,
        "GEN_VAL7":null,
        "GEN_VAL8":null,
        "GEN_VAL9":null,
        "GN_TXT16_2":"                ",
        "GN_TXT24_1":"                        ",
        "GN_TXT32_1":"                                ",
        "GN_TXT32_2":"                                ",
        "GV10_TEXT":"      ",
        "GV1_DATE":null,
        "GV1_FLAG":" ",
        "GV1_TEXT":"SPOT  ",
        "GV1_TIME":null,
        "GV2A_RTIM1":null,
        "GV2A_RTIM2":null,
        "GV2A_RTIM3":null,
        "GV2B_RTIM1":null,
        "GV2B_RTIM2":null,
        "GV2B_RTIM3":null,
        "GV2_DATE":null,
        "GV2_FLAG":" ",
        "GV2_TEXT":"USDCNY",
        "GV2_TIME":null,
        "GV3_FLAG":" ",
        "GV3_TEXT":"      ",
        "GV4_FLAG":" ",
        "GV4_TEXT":"      ",
        "GV5_TEXT":"      ",
        "GV6_TEXT":"      ",
        "GV7_TEXT":"      ",
        "GV8_TEXT":"      ",
        "GV9_TEXT":"      ",
        "HIGHTP_1":"B",
        "HIGH_1":7.2926,
        "HIGH_2":7.2911,
        "HIGH_3":7.2909,
        "HIGH_4":7.2909,
        "HIGH_5":7.2909,
        "HIGH_TIME":"08:26:00",
        "HIGH_TIME2":"08:19:00",
        "HIGH_TIME3":"07:30:00",
        "HIGH_TIME4":"07:30:00",
        "HIGH_TIME5":"07:30:00",
        "HIGH_YLD":null,
        "HSTCLBDDAT":"2023-08-21",
        "HSTCLSDATE":"2023-08-21",
        "HST_CLOSE":7.2865,
        "HST_CLSBID":7.2865,
        "HST_CLSYLD":null,
        "IND_NEWS":"          ",
        "INST_DESC":"                              ",
        "IRGFID":null,
        "IRGPRC":0.0796,
        "IRGVAL":null,
        "LONGLINK1":null,
        "LOWTP_1":"A",
        "LOW_1":7.268,
        "LOW_2":7.268,
        "LOW_3":7.268,
        "LOW_4":7.268,
        "LOW_5":7.268,
        "LOW_TIME":"01:34:00",
        "LOW_TIME2":"01:34:00",
        "LOW_TIME3":"01:34:00",
        "LOW_TIME4":"01:34:00",
        "LOW_TIME5":"01:34:00",
        "LOW_YLD":null,
        "MATUR_DATE":null,
        "MID_1":null,
        "MID_2":null,
        "MID_3":null,
        "MID_NET_CH":null,
        "MID_PRICE":null,
        "MID_SPREAD":null,
        "MONTH_HIGH":null,
        "MONTH_LOW":null,
        "MTD":null,
        "MTHHI_DT":null,
        "MTHLO_DT":null,
        "NETCHNG_1":0.0058,
        "NEWS":"    ",
        "NEWSTM_MS":null,
        "NEWS_TIME":null,
        "NOMINAL":null,
        "NUM_BIDS":null,
        "NUM_MOVES":null,
        "OFFCL_CODE":"MHSH        ",
        "OFFC_CODE2":"            ",
        "OFF_CD_IN2":"   ",
        "OFF_CD_IND":"   ",
        "OPEN_BID":7.267,
        "OPEN_PRC":7.267,
        "OPEN_TIME":"01:34:00",
        "OPEN_TYPE":"B ",
        "OPEN_YLD":null,
        "PCTCHG_3M":null,
        "PCTCHG_6M":null,
        "PCTCHG_INC":null,
        "PCTCHG_MTD":null,
        "PCTCHG_TRT":null,
        "PCTCHG_YTD":null,
        "PCTCHNG":0.08,
        "PREF_DISP":153,
        "PREMIUM":null,
        "PREV_DISP":null,
        "PRIMACT_1":7.2923,
        "PRIMACT_2":7.2911,
        "PRIMACT_3":7.2882,
        "PROD_PERM":363,
        "PROV_SYMB":"                                ",
        "PR_FREQ":"      ",
        "PUTCALLIND":"CALL",
        "P_C_IND1":"    ",
        "QUOTE_TYPE":"   ",
        "QUOTIM_MS":null,
        "RCS_AS_CLA":"   ",
        "RDNDISPLAY":153,
        "RDN_EXCHD2":"NY$",
        "RDN_EXCHID":"   ",
        "RECORDTYPE":209,
        "REL_SPEEDG":null,
        "RIC_DESC":"        ",
        "RT_YIELD_1":null,
        "SALTIM_MS":null,
        "SCALING":"1       ",
        "SC_ACT_TP1":"  ",
        "SC_ACT_TP2":"  ",
        "SC_ACT_TP3":"  ",
        "SC_AFLAG1":" ",
        "SC_AFLAG2":" ",
        "SC_AFLAG3":" ",
        "SEC_ACT_1":7.2929,
        "SEC_ACT_2":7.2925,
        "SEC_ACT_3":7.2885,
        "SEC_HIGH":null,
        "SEC_HI_TP":" ",
        "SEC_LOW":null,
        "SEC_LO_TP":" ",
        "SEC_VOL1":null,
        "SEQNUM":null,
        "SETTLEDATE":null,
        "SPS_SP_RIC":".[SPSEVAI-VAH10-P4",
        "START_DT":null,
        "TERM":null,
        "TIMACT":"08:29:00",
        "TIMCOR":null,
        "TIMCOR_MS":null,
        "TRADE_DATE":null,
        "TRDPRC_1":null,
        "TRDTIM_1":null,
        "TRDTIM_MS":null,
        "TRDVOL_1":null,
        "TRD_UNITS":"4DP ",
        "US_CLOSE":null,
        "US_CL_DT":null,
        "US_HIGH":null,
        "US_HI_TM":null,
        "US_LOW":null,
        "US_LW_TM":null,
        "US_NETCH":null,
        "US_OPEN":null,
        "US_OP_TM":null,
        "VALUE_DT1":"2023-08-22",
        "VALUE_DT2":"2023-08-22",
        "VALUE_DT3":"2023-08-22",
        "VALUE_TS1":"08:29:57",
        "VALUE_TS2":"08:19:04",
        "VALUE_TS3":"08:09:39",
        "WEB_ADRS":"                                                                                ",
        "WEEK_HIGH":null,
        "WEEK_LOW":null,
        "WEIGHTING":null,
        "WKHI_DT":null,
        "WKLO_DT":null,
        "WTD_AVE1":null,
        "YLD_NETCHG":null,
        "YRBDHI_IND":" ",
        "YRBDLO_IND":" ",
        "YRBIDHIGH":7.317,
        "YRBIDLOW":6.6905,
        "YRHIGH":7.317,
        "YRHIGHDAT":null,
        "YRLOW":6.6915,
        "YRLOWDAT":null,
        "YTD":null
      },
      "ID":2,
      "Key":{
        "Name":"CNY=X",
        "Service":"ELEKTRON_DD"
      },
      "PermData":"AwEBNjw=",
      "Qos":{
        "Rate":"JitConflated",
        "Timeliness":"Realtime"
      },
      "SeqNumber":6334,
      "State":{
        "Data":"Ok",
        "Stream":"Open"
      },
      "Type":"Refresh"
    }
  ]
```

The following is the subsequent json message received:

```
[
  {
    "DoNotConflate":true,
    "Fields":{
      "ACTIV_DATE":"2023-08-22",
      "ACT_TP_1":"B\u21e9",
      "ACT_TP_2":"B\u21e7",
      "ACT_TP_3":"B\u21e7",
      "ASK":7.292,
      "ASK_HIGH_1":7.2938,
      "ASK_HI_TME":"08:31:00",
      "ASK_LOW_1":7.268,
      "ASK_LO_TME":"01:34:00",
      "BID":7.2908,
      "BID_HIGH_1":7.2933,
      "BID_LOW_1":7.267,
      "BID_NET_CH":0.0043,
      "BID_TICK_1":"\u21e9",
      "CLOSE_ASK":7.289,
      "CLOSE_BID":7.2865,
      "CLOSE_TYPE":"B ",
      "GV2_TEXT":"USDCNY",
      "HIGHTP_1":"B",
      "HIGH_1":7.2933,
      "HIGH_TIME":"08:34:00",
      "HSTCLBDDAT":"2023-08-21",
      "HSTCLSDATE":"2023-08-21",
      "HST_CLOSE":7.2865,
      "HST_CLSBID":7.2865,
      "IRGPRC":0.059,
      "LOWTP_1":"A",
      "LOW_1":7.268,
      "LOW_TIME":"01:34:00",
      "NETCHNG_1":0.0043,
      "OPEN_BID":7.267,
      "OPEN_PRC":7.267,
      "OPEN_TIME":"01:34:00",
      "OPEN_TYPE":"B ",
      "PCTCHNG":0.06,
      "PRIMACT_1":7.2908,
      "SCALING":"1       ",
      "SEC_ACT_1":7.292,
      "TIMACT":"08:39:00",
      "VALUE_DT1":"2023-08-22",
      "VALUE_TS1":"08:39:04",
      "YRBIDHIGH":7.317,
      "YRBIDLOW":6.6905,
      "YRHIGH":7.317,
      "YRLOW":6.6915
    },
    "ID":2,
    "Key":{
      "Name":"CNY=X",
      "Service":"ELEKTRON_DD"
    },
    "SeqNumber":6350,
    "Type":"Update",
    "UpdateType":"Unspecified"
  }
]
```

The above code is what I tried. Please help. I've been googling for weeks and still couldn't figure it out....

Comment: Surely you could have posted a much smaller program that demonstrates the issue you are having. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example)(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You say, "But somehow the second thread doesn't seem to be starting or the data are not appended to the list so that there is nothing to print." How hard would it be to determine which of these alternatives is occurring by inserting some debugging `print` statements in the right place? (More ...)

Comment: If one thread is constantly appending to list `dataBuffer` and the second thread has a `for data in dataBuffer:` loop, what happens if this second thread executes the `if len(dataBuffer) > 0:` check before any message has been appended to the list by the first thread? Answer: The loop terminates immediately, the thread will end and nothing will get printed. Do not use a `dataBuffer` list instance. Use a `queue.Queue` instance to which the first thread puts data and the second thread does blocking get calls. By the way, you have an indentation error in `process_data`.

Comment: Using queue.Queue works! Thank you so much. But why doesn't list work? Because even if I don't do the checking (if len(dataBuffer) > 0:), nothing get printed. You already solved my question, but I just want to know more if you don't mind. Again Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The following loop `for data in dataBuffer:` iterates each element of `dataBuffer`. But if the length of that list is 0, that implies there are no elements in the list and so the `for` loop's body will not get executed even once. So the check you do before executing that `for` loop, namely checking the length of the list for being greater than 0, is totally redundant and serves no useful purpose. Thus, removing the length check is not going to make any difference in the result (the for loop ultimately implicitly checks the length of the list).

Comment: But wouldn't the list eventually have data? Or are you saying that once the for loop dosen't get execuated, the thread ends as well? But why doesn't queue have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw your comment/question. To be sure I am notified of your new comment, prefix it with @Booboo.

The list might eventually have data but it could be too late. If `process_data` finds an empty list the function terminates and when it does the thread terminates. If there is data, your code will always print out *all* the elements of the list that meet your criteria and then terminate. If the other thread is constantly adding data to this list, you would prefer to never terminate and print out new, relevant data. A queue contains "messages." The receiver can make a call to get the next item on the queue and the item is then automatically removed from the queue so it will never be processed again by the receiver. Moreover, if there is no message on the queue, the receiver will block until there is a message. This removes all timing considerations.

As long as you are using multithreading rather than multiprocessing, the simplest change is to modify the code to define a global queue:

```py
from functools import partial
import sys
import time
import getopt
import requests
import socket
import json
import websocket
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process

from queue import Queue

queue = Queue()
...
```

If you change to use multiprocessing *and* you are running under a platform that uses the *fork* method to create child processes, (e.g. Linux), then you want:

```py
...
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

queue = Queue()
```

Then `process_data` is modifed as follows:

```py
def process_data(dataBuffer):
    while True: # Loop forever
        data = queue.get() # Blocks until there is something on the queue
           
        if data['Key']['Name'] == "CNY=X":
            ... # etc.
```

Then get rid of all references to `dataBuffer`. Wherever you were appending to `dataBuffer`, for example, `dataBuffer.append(message_json)`, change the code to be `queue.put(message_json)`.